# Remotly set inputbox and send it

Tags: php, python, html, bash, input

I have remote website (not mine)

```
<input type=text id="num" name="num" size="10" maxlength="10"/> 
<a id="setnum" href="#">Send</a>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Is there any way of seting inputbox and sending a form?

Comment: you mean you want to programatically fill out a form and submit it? yes. there are lots of ways to do that. you can issue a POST straight to the destination (look at 'action' in <form> tag)....is the easiest way.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Can you give me more detail/name what I exacly looking for? (I dont know how to ask Google for it)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, send a `GET` or `POST` (depending on the form's `method=` attribute) to the location specified in the form's `action=` attribute including your data in `key=value` pairs where `key` is the `name=` attribute of the input element, and `value` is the wanted value.

If you want some Google keywords:

> How to send a POST request in `<insert your favorite programming language here>`

Comment: Hmm... So I do have to guess action= dont I?

Comment: @Ultra: No, you'll need to look at it. It should be set in the `<form>` element. If it's not, the `action=` should be the same page as the form (but it should be set).

Comment: @Ultra: I highly recommend the browser extension [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for seeing form information.

Comment: @Lenna: All the information he needs is usually found right in the source, no extensions needed.

Comment: @Truth: Nevertheless, I find the graphical labeling of form boxes to be much easier to read.